# How to fix overlapping tick lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting with different colors for x and y axis - it's become visible that ticks overlapping badly with each other and take start from middle of axis line. With colorful axis and high dpi it's look terrible. How to fix it?

[image: example]